How to clear pydantic object to default values (reset to defaults)?
I need default values to be cleared in a Pydantic model. I cannot recreate the object because, in my use case, it has references that need to be preserved. Could you please show me the best practices for this?
I need something like this example.
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class MyObject(BaseModel):
    value: int = Field(default=1)


my_object = MyObject(value1=2)

# Reference to object, that need to be preserved
reference = [my_object]

# How to clear object to default values?
my_object.clear()
assert reference[0].value == 1


https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/3139

Should be value: int = Field(default=1, validate_default=True)

pydantic library provides just the right tools to do this with the BaseModel class.
What you have to do is to define your clear method to your class :
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

    def foo():
        return 2


    class MyObject(BaseModel):
        value1: int = Field(default=1)
        value2: Any = Field(default=foo())
        ...

        def clear(self):
            for field, field_info in self.model_fields.items():
                if field_info.default_factory:
                    default_value = field_info.default_factory()
                else:
                    default_value = field_info.default
                setattr(self, field, default_value)
            self.model_fields_set.clear()

What it does is :

iterate through every one of the fields set in your BaseModel. (contained in the model_fields dictionary).
check (with the if/else statement) the nature of the given field (was its default value set by constant, as in your example, or by a callable, here with the foo function)
fetch its default value
reset it

all the above done without recreating an instance. Now
my_object = MyObject(value1=2)

# Reference to object, that need to be preserved
reference = [my_object]

# How to clear object to default values?
my_object.clear()
assert reference[0].value == 1

Shouldn't raise any error!
Feel free to ask any question

please, fix the indentation in your code snippets. Indentation is not a "pretty thing" in Python - it is a fundamental part of the syntax: your code as is  boils down do SyntaxError.
Note that you can use triple backward ticks as quotes for code, instead of pre-pending four spaces to every line of code to get the formatting.

@jsbueno Thank you for noticing my mistake. indentation is indeed crucial. thanks for the triple backward tip, I didn't know.

I would highly recommend to make it as explicitly as possible. Your methods should be easy to read and understandable at a glance. Moreover think about scalability and potential errors, for example, when adding new nested attributes or when some of attribute don't have a default value.
You can move out your values to constants additionally, but the idea is following:
class Bar(BaseModel):
    value: int | None = Field(default=None)

    def clear(self) -> None:
        """Revert all Bar values back to the default ones."""

        self.value = None

class Foo(BaseModel):
    value: int = Field(default=1)
    bar: Bar


    def clear(self):
        """Revert all Foo values back to the default ones."""

        self.value = 1
        self.bar.clear()


foo = Foo()
foo.clear()


The problem with this is that the defaults are defined two places: in the Field definition, and within the clear method. This violates the "DRY" principle
